# Android spinner selected position with byte convertion logic

Tags: android, byte

I have a piece of code obtain from a source which I need to understand regarding byte conversion and use from android spinner -

**Edit: ---------------------------------------**

So I was playing around with this binary operations and I don't know how these statements decide the output-

A. How the "and" plays role here?
B. Why do we need to convet it to int using toInt()? The output was same even without using it.

```
var biteData = ByteArray(2)
biteData[0] = (1 and 0xFF)
biteData[1] = (0 and 0xFF)
testByteToInt(biteData)
testByteToInt1(biteData)
testByteToInt2(biteData)
testByteToInt3(biteData)

fun testByteToInt(bytes:ByteArray){
    val item_one:Byte = (bytes[0] +  0xFF and 0x01).toByte()
    var one_item = item_one.toInt()
    print(one_item)
}

// output: 0

fun testByteToInt1(bytes:ByteArray){
    val item_one:Byte = (bytes[0] +  0x01 and 0xFF).toByte()
    var one_item = item_one.toInt()
    print(one_item)
}

// output: 2

fun testByteToInt2(bytes:ByteArray){
    val item_one:Byte = ((bytes[0] +  0xFF) and 0x01).toByte()
    var one_item = item_one.toInt()
    print(one_item)
}

// output: 0

fun testByteToInt3(bytes:ByteArray){
    val item_one:Byte = ((bytes[0] +  0x01) and 0xFF).toByte()
    var one_item = item_one.toInt()
    print(one_item)
}
 
// output: 2
```

```
class MyClass{
     public byte[] getSpinnerVal(View view){
         byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
         Spinner spinner = null;
         spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_one);
         byte[0] = (byte) (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() & 0xFF)
         spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_two);
         byte[1] = (byte) (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() & 0xFF)
     }
    
     void setSpinnerVal(byte val_one,byte val_two,View view){
         Spinner spinner = null;
         spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_one);
         spinner.setSelection((byte) ((val_one - 0x01) & 0xFF));
         spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_two);
         spinner.setSelection((byte) ((val_two - 0x01) & 0xFF)); 
     }
    
}

void onCreate(){
    MyClass mclass = new MyClass()
    byte[] bytes = mclass.getSpinnerVal(spinner_view);
    byte item_one = (byte) ((bytes[0] + 0x01) & 0xFF);
    byte item_two = (byte) ((bytes[1] + 0x01) & 0xFF);
    mclass.setSpinnerVal(some_byte_val_one, some_byte_val_two, spinner_view);
}
```

What I am confused about is this line where selected value gets increment by one

```
    byte item_one = (byte) ((bytes[0] + 0x01) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: what is the problem again ? or you just want to understand how that line works ?

Comment: @rajan.kali I just wanted to understand that while setting up the value

Comment: @rajan.kali can please check my cpmment on your answer posted and my edit in the question? Thank you so much agian :)

Answer (score 0):

All it does is simple `byte` addition, A `byte` is `8 bits`, so the upper bound with all one's would be `256(1111 1111`) which is represented as `0xFF` in hex, same goes for `1` in hex `0x01`

```
byte item_two = (byte) ((bytes[1] + 0x01) & 0xFF);
//say byte[1] = 1, whose binary representation is 0000 0001 
//0x01 = 0000 0001
//Now if you do (bytes[1] + 0x01)
//  0000 0001 //byte[1] value, which is position 1
// +0000 0001 // incremental value of 1
//  0000 0010 // which equals to 2
// and by doing [& 0xFF] is to limit the upper bound.
```

Comment: I understood that part when I logged the data. I wanted to know why we are incrementing the value by one?